How to extend this main/AndroidManifest.xml redirect activity block using the dev/AndroidManifest.xml?
I have a main AndroidManifest.xml file and I want to add 1 more data inside the intent-filter using the dev AndroidManifest.xml file, so that the resulting merged manifest looks like this:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        <activity
            android:name="com.auth0.android.provider.RedirectActivity"
            tools:node="replace"
            android:readPermission="com.auth0.android.provider.READ_PERMISSION"
            android:writePermission="com.auth0.android.provider.WRITE_PERMISSION"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="example1.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/android/com.example/callback"
                    android:scheme="com.example.auth0" />
                <data
                    android:host="example2.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/android/com.example/callback"
                    android:scheme="com.example.auth0" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

What I have in my main AndroidManifest.xml right now is the following:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        <activity
            android:name="com.auth0.android.provider.RedirectActivity"
            tools:node="replace"
            android:readPermission="com.auth0.android.provider.READ_PERMISSION"
            android:writePermission="com.auth0.android.provider.WRITE_PERMISSION"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="example1.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/android/com.example/callback"
                    android:scheme="com.example.auth0" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

And my dev AndroidManifest.xml is empty:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

</manifest>

